# Add-on or extension for Dia - Diagram editor

Tags: linux, dia, mockup-tool

No doubt Dia is a great tool in Linux. All linux users might have come across it. It is my best friend all the time when I want to design UML ERD or Database etc.

I wonder if it has any add on or extension that can help me in GUI/Web application prototyping. Any idea??

Answer (score 0):

What exactly would you like this Plugin to do? Maybe it can be implemented with some lines of Python code.